# Глюк с отправкой формы в IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

В общем, есть задача адаптировать проект так, чтобы он работал в IE8. Не спрашивайте, зачем :)

Проблема с отправкой файловой формы (multipart/formdata). После вызова

`document.getElementById('fileForm').submit()`

браузер "падает" с ошибкой "Отказано в доступе". Домен, на который отправляется файл - тот же, с точностью до поддомена. Форма скрытая правда, точнее файл-инпут, но вроде его никто и не делает обычно видимым?

Люди, знающие тонкости разработки под IE, откликнитесь плиз.

Comment: Мда, походу и правда не даёт скрыть. Ни через visibility, ни через прозрачность, ни отрицательной координатой. А с видимым - работает, по крайней мере, когда файл выбираю кликом на самом инпуте. Неужели во времена IE8 никак файл-инпуты нельзя было стилизовать?

Comment: В старых IE это действительно блокируется. Вопрос, где вызывается `.submit()`. Крайне желательно, чтобы это было в обработчике `onclick()`, который вызвался от клика _пользователя_, а не интерпретатора, не важно где произошел клик, но он должен быть) В свое время так решил эту проблему.

Comment: Значит, придётся для IE делать отдельное окно всплывающее с обычной формой. Увы, в обработчике там никак: на onclick по div-у повешен click по input, а на onchange у input-а - form.submit(), типовая схема. Не знал, что в IE так нельзя :)